# Unable to run xrdb command to resize cursor when logging in

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, high-dpi

happy XFCE4 user here,

I (unluckily) switched to a notebook with 4k display.

I managed to adapt most of the aspects, still when hovering on Chrome or Xfce Terminal **the cursor is tiny**.

I found that running `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` where `~/.Xresources` contains:

```
Xcursor.size: 48
```

fixes the problem — still have to check the result on an external monitor.

**Now the problem is how do I run the command when the computer starts!**

I put this in `~/.xprofile`:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

which seems to be executed, nevertheless the cursor problem remains.

I suppose some command is resetting it because if I open a terminal and I manually give the `xrdb  -merge ~/.Xresources` command again it gets sorted at last